# Issue with apipie gem and rspec in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec

i'm writing the code to get my Rspec tests to pass on my api. I'm using the apipie gem to generate documentation and it seems that my tests are failing because thy are expecting a number and it's funny because this is exactly what I want to test.
The page fails when the :bpm parameter is not a number. is there any way of going around this ?

```
context "when is not created" do
  before(:each) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    @invalid_lesson_attributes = { title: "California Dreamin",
                                   bpm: "Hello"

    }
    request.headers['Authorization'] =  user.auth_token
    post :create, { user_id: user.id, lesson: @invalid_lesson_attributes }
  end


  it "renders an errors json" do
    lesson_response = json_response
    expect(lesson_response).to have_key(:errors)
  end
  it "renders the json errors on why the user could not be created" do
    lesson_response = json_response
    expect(lesson_response[:errors][:bpm]).to include "is not a number"
  end

  it { should respond_with 422 }

  end
end
```

Update spec:

```
context "when is not updated" do
  before(:each) do
    patch :update, { user_id: @user.id, id: @lesson.id,
                     lesson: { bpm: "ten" }, format: :json }
  end

  it "renders an errors json" do
    lesson_response = json_response
    expect(lesson_response).to have_key(:errors)
  end

  it "renders the json errors on why the user could not be updated" do
    lesson_response = json_response
    expect(lesson_response[:errors][:bpm]).to include "is not a number"
  end

  it { should respond_with 422 }
end
```

in my users_controller:

```
api :POST, '/teachers/:user_id/lessons/', "Create lesson"
param :lesson, Hash, desc: 'Lesson information', :required => true do
  param :title, String, desc: 'Title of the lesson', :required => true
  param :bpm, :number, desc: 'tempo of the lesson (beats per second)', :required => true

end
error :code => 422, :desc => "Unprocessable Entity"
```

my error when I run my rspec tests :

```
Apipie::ParamInvalid: Invalid parameter 'bpm' value "Hello": Must be a number.
```

Answer (score 0):

Adds format json to post request

```
post :create, { user_id: user.id, lesson: @invalid_lesson_attributes, format: :json }
```

That worked for me.

Comment: worked for the :create but not for the :update. I edited my code to show the update. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I used method update instead of patch 
`put :update, { id: event[:id], event: event_attributes, format: :json }` work for me